# $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$

Tags: proof-verification

I tried a proof using mainly the Archimedean property of $\Bbb R$:

I am to show that for any $x\in \Bbb R$, every neighborhood of $x$ contains a rational number.
I shall first prove it for non-negative real numbers. Suppose $x$ is a non-negative real number and let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean property, there is an $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $n\epsilon >1$ i.e. $\frac 1n<\epsilon$.
Again, using the Archimedean property, we can find an $m\in \Bbb N$ such that $m\frac 1n >x$.

Let $S=${$m\in \Bbb N : \frac mn>x$}.
Since $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb N$, it has a least element, say, $m'$. It means one of the following:

A) $m'-1$ is a natural number with the property that $\frac {m'-1}n≤x$; or

B) $m'-1=0$ whence $m'=1$.

A) If possible assume that neither $\frac {m'-1}n$ nor $\frac {m'}n$ belong in $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Which means :

$\frac{m'-1}n<x-\epsilon<x+\epsilon<\frac{m'}n \implies (x+\epsilon) - (x-\epsilon)<\frac{m'}n - \frac{m'-1}n \implies 2\epsilon<\frac 1n<\epsilon$ which is a contradiction. Thus one of them must be in $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

B) $m'=1$ means that $\frac 1n>x$. But since $x$ is non-negative we also have $\frac 1n<\epsilon<x+\epsilon$. Hence, $\frac 1n\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Thus every neighborhood $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ of $x$ contains a rational number $q$. But then, the neighborhood $(-x-\epsilon,-x+\epsilon)$ of $-x$ contains the rational number $-q$. This completes my proof.

Is the proof okay?

Comment: It seems to be correct.  You can probably try to make it simpler.

Comment: @fleablood Okay. I will try.

Comment: Just a comment:  This seems to be a strange problem, because $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the normal absolute value.  What I mean is, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ by definition.

Comment: @Dzoooks there are many definitions of $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ can be defined as the only complete ordered field (up to isomorphism), by Dedekind cuts, by completing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a metric space, etc.

Comment: @Dzoooks I don't know the definition of density you used. What I understand by  $\Bbb Q$ being dense in $\Bbb R$ is that every point of $\Bbb R$ is a closure point of $\Bbb Q$

Comment: @Dzoooks to say the R is defined as the completion of Q is to assume Q has a completion.

Comment: @HritRoy Dzoooks' point is that R by definition *is* Q and its closure points. But an excercise equivalent to yours must, IMO, be done eventually to prove Q can be completed with closure points.

Comment: @fleablood I don't know what is meant by the "completion" of $\Bbb Q$ yet. However, if $\Bbb Q$ was dense in $\Bbb R$ axiomatically or something, wouldn't I, at some point, have to invoke that axiom (directly or indirectly) in order to prove the above?

Comment: @HritRoy  It depends on your definition of $\mathbb{R}$.  If your definition is anything other than the completion wrt to usual $|\cdot |$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, then proving $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ is an exercise worth doing.  If, as is probably the case, your definition of $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, then this exercise is true by definition.

Comment: @HritRoy Definitions and particulars aside though, the easiest way to see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in "$\mathbb{R}$", imo is to look at decimal expansions.  Take $\pi$, for example.  It's approximated arbitrarily well by the sequence of rational numbers $3, 3.1, 3.14, $ etc.

Comment: With all due respect to Dzoooks, he is assuming there is an intuitive sense of the meaning of the reals as being "the rationals with all the holes filled in".  The decimmal expansions *assume* that the reals are well-defined and that every real number has an infinite expansion and every infinite decimal is a real number.  IMO that is not an acceptable assumption.  However, if I were you, Hrit Roy, I wouldn't worry too much.  Eventually, we must prove that rational numbers are dense ... within themselves (that is within any interval there is an rational number).  So I'm glad you did it.

Comment: @Dzoooks - The essential property of the real numbers is that it is - up to isomorphism - the unique topologically complete ordered field. Building from sets $\to \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Q \to \Bbb R$ is simply a way of showing such a field exists. But $\Bbb R$ itself should be considered an otherwise undistinguished complete ordered field. $\Bbb Q$ is then the smallest subfield, $\Bbb Z$ is the smallest unital subring, and $\Bbb N$ the smallest set containing $1$ (and $0$, depending on your choice of definition) which is closed under addition.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Please direct helpful responses at the OP.  It's pedantic to assume that I didn't know this stuff..

Comment: @Dzoooks - why then did you proclaim to the OP that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ "by definition" if you knew differently?